# Loading a cookie and posting data with curl

Tags: php, cookies, curl, http-post

If I load in a cookie, I am able to get to the page that requires cookies, like this:

```
$cookie = ".ASPXAUTH=Secret";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
```

No problem here, I can run `curl_exec`, and see the page that requires cookies.

If I also want to send some post data, I can do like this:

```
$data = array(
     'index' => "Some data is here"
);

$cookie = ".ASPXAUTH=Secret";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
```

I have set up a [dump script](http://pastebin.com/37mDNNHr) on my local server, to see if it is working. If i send **only** the cookie, I can see it in the http headers, and if I send **only** the post data, I can see the post data.

When I send both, I see only the cookie.

Why?

Comment: ummm what does the script look like that you are sending these curl requests to?

Comment: @Neal I'm currently only posting to a dump script on a local server. The script is found here http://pastebin.com/37mDNNHr

Comment: What's the contents of php://input? Maybe the HTTP contents aren't being parsed into the $_POST variable properly depending on how curl sends the Content-Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

If I manually set the cookie, using a custom http_header, I am able to get the results wanted.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie:.ASPXAUTH=secretData"));
```

Even tried on different servers - same results.